How to extract all xml data (including xml tags) using Suitescript
Hope you can help. I am currently assessing the best way to extract ALL 'OrderLevel' tags (this would include both tags and values) from an XML file in SuiteScript 2.1.
Here's an example snippet:
<RootLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>123</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>fridge</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>abc</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>456</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>cupboard</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>def</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
</RootLevel>

This is a very simple example of course. I was considering using a REGEX pattern, but I would rather a method that is considered best practice.
The whole goal of this exercise is to combine all  tags from multiple XML files into one single XML file. To be clear, I do not want just the values, but also the tags.
Thoughts?
EDIT: Taking advice frim @Krypton, here is the SuiteScript code I have attempted to write:
// file to copy from
            var childFile = file.load({id: value.fileId});
            var childXmlContents = childFile.getContents();
            log.debug('childXmlContents',childXmlContents);
            var childXmlData = xml.Parser.fromString({text: childXmlContents});

 //file to copy to
            var parentFile = file.load({id: value.parentFileId});
            var parentXmlContents = parentFile.getContents();
            log.debug('parentXmlContents',parentXmlContents);
            var parentXmlData = xml.Parser.fromString({text: parentXmlContents});

//Capture root node from parent file: We aim to copy node from child file.
           const parentRootNode = parentXmlData.getElementsByTagName('RootLevel')[0];

//Capture orderLevel node from child file
           var orderXMLElement = childXmlData.getElementsByTagName({tagName: 'OrderLevel'});

//Loop through each orderLevel node of child file, COPY node, then append to root of parent file    
           for (var i = 0; i < orderXMLElement.length; i++) {
                var x = childXmlData.getElementsByTagName('OrderLevel')[i];
                var getCloneNode = x.cloneNode(true);
                parentRootNode.appendChild(getCloneNode);
           }

//Return parent XML as string and save file
           const newFileStr = xml.Parser.toString({document: parentXmlData});
           const xmlFile = createXMLFile(parentFile.name, newFileStr, 6485323);
           const xmlFileId = xmlFile.save();

The latest error I am receiving: SSS_XML_DOM_EXCEPTION WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
Ideas on what I could be doing wrong?


This appears to be a question about XML manipulation, more than about SuiteScript - SuiteScript doesn't typically deal with XML as in the general use case there's no need.



That being the case, assuming this is related to server side scripting, you could simply load an XML DOM parser like xmldom and use that to load, manipulate, extract and create whatever XML documents you need.


SuiteScript has its own dedicated 'N/xml' module though; I wanted to know if there was any best practices via the native SuiteScript API I can use to extract data.


Zooming out a bit, what it the broader context where this is required?  Where are you getting the XML files and what do you ultimately want to do with them?


The XML files are held in a folder on the filing cabinet of NetSuite. I want to extract all OrderLevel tags (and its data) within it from each file, and combine all of them in one single XML file.

I see.  I've never used that module, but it sounds like that might be the answer to your question!  Have you attempted to create a script to parse and manipulate your XML files using that N/xml module?  If so you should post it along with a description of what it's doing and how it's falling short of what you want

Sure @Krypton, I have updated my description above. Open to any assistance.

You can use the N/xml module to manipulate XML files.  A simple example of this is as follows - you would need to handle the loading of the files separately, this just demonstrates the XML side of it:
require(['N'], function(N) {
for(var n in N){window[n] = N[n];};

    let p = xml.Parser;
    let xmlString = `<RootLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>123</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>fridge</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>abc</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>456</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>cupboard</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>def</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
</RootLevel>`;
    let xmlString2 = `
    <RootLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>4567</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>computer</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>xyz</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
  <OrderLevel>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>6542</PurchaseOrderNumber>
      <item>mouse</item>
    <PurchaseOrderDate/>
    <Vendor>pqr</Vendor>
  </OrderLevel>
</RootLevel>
    `
    let xmlDoc = p.fromString({
        text: xmlString
    });
    let xmlDoc2 = p.fromString({
        text: xmlString2
    });
    let xmlDocs = [xmlDoc,xmlDoc2];
    let orderNodes = [];
    xmlDocs.forEach( x => {
        let orderNodesDoc = xml.XPath.select({
            node:x,
            xpath: '//OrderLevel'
        });
        orderNodes.push.apply(orderNodes, orderNodesDoc);
    })
    console.log(orderNodes);
    let newXmlDoc = p.fromString({
        text: '<NewRoot></NewRoot>'
    });
    let newRootNode = newXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('NewRoot')[0];
        
    console.log('newXmlDoc',newXmlDoc);
    console.log(orderNodes.length);
    for (i=0;i<orderNodes.length;i++) {
        let orderNode = newXmlDoc.importNode(orderNodes[i], true);
        newRootNode.appendChild(orderNode);
    }

    console.log(newXmlDoc);
    let newXmlString = p.toString({
        document: newXmlDoc
    });
    console.log('newXmlString', newXmlString);
    let oldXmlString = p.toString({
        document: xmlDoc
    });
    console.log('oldXmlString', oldXmlString);
})

Note that this is using the require function - you can copy and paste it into your browser's dev tools console and run it directly, but will need to modify it to use define for your production script.
HTH!

Great, many thanks again. 'importNode' and 'cloneNode' appear to work the same way?

As indicated in earlier comments, I'm not very familiar with this module, or indeed XML in general.  However, my understanding so far is that cloneNode does not allow the node to be used in another document.  I suppose it's just for creating additional nodes with the same structure within the same document.  Whereas importNode is specifically for copying a node from one document to another.
